# explanation about converting milliseconds to minutes

Tags: java

```
public String timeDifference(String startTime, String leavedTime) {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    Date date1;
    String dd =null;

    try {
        date1 = format.parse(startTime);
        Date date2 = format.parse(leavedTime);
    long difference = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
    long diffMinutes = difference / (60 * 1000) % 60;
    long diffHours = difference / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;

     dd=diffHours + " : " + diffMinutes ;

    } catch (ParseException ex) {
       System.out.println(ex);
    }
    return dd;
}
```

I want to know about ,

```
1)long diffMinutes = difference / (60 * 1000) % 60;
  2)          long diffHours = difference / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24
```

what is the purpose of using % 60 in code 1
 what is the purpose of using % 24 in code 2

can anyone give me a clear explanation?

Comment: Do you know what `%` is and does?

Comment: Do you know what operator precedence and associativity say about the order of evaluation of those expressions?

Comment: Have you tried taking out the `% 60` and `% 24` to see how it affects the output?

Comment: yes i tried it doesn't make any difference in the output so what is the purpose of using that ( % 60 and % 24)

Comment: actually as i know brackects () is in the priority, after done the calculation inside brackets then go to the modulus operater

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%` operator is the modulus operation.  In this code, `diffMinutes` will be the number of minutes within the hour of the time difference, and `diffHours` will be the number of hours within the time difference.

Dividing by `(60 * 1000)` converts the original difference in milliseconds to units of minutes (divide by 1000 to get seconds, then by 60 to get minutes).

For example, if the time difference is 2 days 3 hours and 52 minutes, `diffMinutes` will be 52 and `diffHours` will be 3.

Without the modulus, the result changes from "the number of minutes *within the hour*" to "the total number of elapsed minutes".  For example, 133 minutes elapsed (without the modulus) becomes "13 minutes within the hour" with the modulus.

Comment: what you have mentioned is i already known, what i need to know is  difference / (60 * 1000) % 60;     in this statement after converting difference in milliseconds to units of minutes then what is the purpose of using % 60 here. what we want is already got by this follow statement ,isn't it (difference / (60 * 1000)) (Imean without modulus)